# How do you clear variable values held in a switch function?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have been working on this project for school for several weeks now and have came here several times to point me back in the right direction, so thank you for that.
This is the issue I (and my instructor) are struggling over.

I have to create an order form (...yep) where the user must select a computer case, monitor, and printer. The picture must appear next to the selection and the price must update. If everything checks the order submits, if not you get an alert asking to complete the form. You also have the option to reset or clear the form. Everything work wonderfully except the clear function. All fields reset including the price, however the individual values are still being held. If I pick the first option on all sections the total is $1000, after I clear it the total field shows zero. Then, if I pick another option from group A, the values are still totaling with group B and C as if nothing was cleared.

Hope I explained that clearly, here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function doSubmit()
{
 if (validateText() == false)
  {
   alert("Please Complete Customer Information");
   return;
  }
 if (validateRadio() == false)
  {
   alert("Please Select a Case")
   return;
  }
 if (validateRadio1() == false)
  {
   alert("Please Select a Monitor")
   return;
  }
 if (validateRadio2() == false)
  {
   alert("Please Select a Printer")
   return;
  }
 alert("Order Accepted. Thank you.");
 return;
}

function validateText()
{
 var customer = document.Form4.customer.value;
 if (customer.length == 0) return false;
 var address1 = document.Form4.address1.value;
 if (address1.length == 0) return false;
 var city = document.Form4.city.value;
 if (city.length == 0) return false;
 var phone = document.Form4.phone.value;
 if (phone.length == 0) return false;
 var email = document.Form4.email.value;
 if (email.length == 0) return false;
 return true;
}

function validateRadio()
{
 if (document.Form1.case[0].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form1.case[1].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form1.case[2].checked) return true;
 return false;
}

function validateRadio1()
{
 if (document.Form2.screen[0].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form2.screen[1].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form2.screen[2].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form2.screen[3].checked) return true;
 return false;
}

function validateRadio2()
{
 if (document.Form3.printer[0].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form3.printer[1].checked) return true;
 if (document.Form3.printer[2].checked) return true;
 return false;
}

function doClear()
{
 document.Form4.systotal.value = "0.00";
 document.Form4.customer.value = "";
 document.Form4.address1.value = "";
 document.Form4.address2.value = "";
 document.Form4.city.value = "";
 document.Form4.state.value = "";
 document.Form4.zip.value = "";
 document.Form4.phone.value = "";
 document.Form4.email.value = "";

 document.Form1.case[0].checked = false;
 document.Form1.case[1].checked = false;
 document.Form1.case[2].checked = false;

 document.Form2.screen[0].checked = false;
 document.Form2.screen[1].checked = false;
 document.Form2.screen[2].checked = false;
 document.Form2.screen[3].checked = false;

 document.Form3.printer[0].checked = false;
 document.Form3.printer[1].checked = false;
 document.Form3.printer[2].checked = false;
 document.Form3.printer[3].checked = false;

 formPics(11);

 return;
}



var computerCase = 0;
var printer = 0;
var monitor = 0;
var total = 0;

function formPics(radios)
{ 
 switch(radios)
  {
   case 1:
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML = "<img src='C1_Game.jpg'>"; 
    computerCase = 600.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 2:
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML = "<img src='C2_Home.jpg'>";
    computerCase = 500.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 3:
    document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML = "<img src='C3_Mini.jpg'>";
    computerCase = 400.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 4:
    document.getElementById("pics2").innerHTML = "<img src='S1_27.jpg'>";
    monitor = 350.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 5:
    document.getElementById("pics2").innerHTML = "<img src='S2_19.jpg'>";
    monitor = 250.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 6:
    document.getElementById("pics2").innerHTML = "<img src='S3_17.jpg'>";
    monitor = 150.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 7:
    document.getElementById("pics2").innerHTML = "<img src='S4_Proj.jpg'>";
    monitor = 650.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 8:
    document.getElementById("pics3").innerHTML = "<img src='P1_Ink.jpg'>";
    printer = 50.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 9:
    document.getElementById("pics3").innerHTML = "<img src='P2_Laser.jpg'>";
    printer = 80.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 10:
    document.getElementById("pics3").innerHTML = "<img src='P3_Color.jpg'>";
    printer = 100.00;
    total = computerCase + printer + monitor;
    document.Form4.systotal.value = total;
    break;
   case 11:
    computerCase = 0;
    printer = 0;
    monitor = 0;
    total = 0;
    break;
  }
}

function totalclear()
{
if(printer > 0)
printer = 0;
return printer;
} 


</script>

<style>
table{ width:800px}
#pics{ float: right;}
#pics2{ float: right;}
#pics3{ float: right;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1 align="center">New System Order Form</h1>

<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<form name="Form1" align="left"> 
 <h3>Choose a Case:</h3><div id='pics'></div>
  <input name="case" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(1)'>Gaming Behemoth ($600.00)<br/> 
  <input name="case" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(2)'>Basic Home Computing ($500.00)                <br/>
  <input name="case" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(3)'>Mini Entertainment Center     ($400.00)<br/>
</form>

<br/>

<form name="Form2"> 
 <h3>Choose a Monitor:</h3><div id='pics2'></div>
  <input name="screen" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(4)'>27" UHD LED ($350.00)<br/>
  <input name="screen" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(5)'>19"HD LCD ($250.00)<br/>
  <input name="screen" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(6)'>17"HD LCD ($150.00)<br/> 
  <input name="screen" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(7)'>HD Laser Projector ($650.00)    <br/>
</form>

<br/>

<form name="Form3"> 
 <h3>Choose a Printer:</h3><div id='pics3'></div>
  <input name="printer" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(8)'>Inkjet Printer ($50.00)      <br/>
  <input name="printer" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(9)'>Laser Printer ($80.00)<br/>
  <input name="printer" type="radio"  onClick='formPics(10)'>Color Laser Printer    ($100.00)<br/> 
</form>

</td>
<form name="Form4">
<td>
<h3 align="left">System Total: $ <input type="text" name="systotal" size="10" readonly     = "readonly" value = "0.00"  /></h3>

<hr style="width:100%" />
<h3 align="left">Customer Information:</h3>

  <b>Full Name:</b><br/>
  <input name="customer" size="45" type="text"><br/>
  <b>Address:</b><br/>
  <input name="address1" size="45" type="text"><br/>
  <input name="address2" size="45" type="text"><br/>
  <b>City, State, and Zip:</b><br/>
  <input name="city" size="15 type="text">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="state" size="2" type="text">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="zip" size="5" type="text"><br/>
 <b>Phone:</b><br/>
  <input name="phone" size="40" type="text"><br/>
 <b>Email:</b><br/>
  <input name="email" size="40" type="text"><br/>
</form>
<hr style="width:100%" />
<br/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" Value="Reset Order" onClick="doClear()">

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have three printers, but you try to clear four. The code in the function `doClear` gives this error message:

```
TypeError: document.Form3.printer[3] is undefined
```

As the code crashes there, the call to `formPics(11)` is never executed, so the variables are never cleared.

Comment: That's what it was. Thank you very much you guys are awesome!